# 3D image comparison in TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete

HOw ot compare 3D image files in testcomplete. My application processes some 3D images i want it to be compared with the reference. Image file types are .spt, .vtk, .mdb ,.dcm.
Someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use checkpoints for this purpose. For example:

- To verify an image displayed on screen, use a *region checkpoint*.
- To verify the actual file that holds the image data, use a *file checkpoint*.

Comment: i want  to compare 2 .spt files. i couldnt add them to the Regions or Files store. is ther any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for DICOM images you could think about converting those into bitmaps and have TestComplete compare the bitmaps. Admitted, there is one additional step that you have to take care of, and this is the choice of a (command line) tool that does the conversion for you. I think IrfanView does the job. Give it a try and post your results.